# How can I boot into a chroot, without leaving the current OS session?

Tags: boot, chroot

I'm building Linux systems, turn them into ISOs and then test them in a VM.

But that step takes minutes, which I would like to avoid, while developing.

Is there a way I can take the files, which are basically forming a chroot, and boot them, without having to reboot my host machine?

Edit:

What I want to do is, use the kernel of my chroot to boot it into basically a VM. I want to avoid the step of having to build an ISO just for the VM to have something to boot.

Comment: So what you're wanting is for a vm to boot a portion of your already mounted filesystem?  If the system you're building is in a separate file system you could, in theory, un-mount it and configure a vm to boot from the underlying block device for that filesystem.  How you would do it would really depend on what kind of vm's you're running (ie, kvm, vmware, virtualbox, etc.)

Comment: What do you meant by “boot into a chroot”? You can execute a program in the chroot simply by running `chroot /path/to/root /path/to/program`. At the other extreme, if you want to run the kernel from the ISO, you need a VM, by definition.

Comment: @DavidKing That seems like exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Actually, you want to test your kernel serveral times?

Comment: @davidbaumann I basically build Live DVDs. And I don't want to have to actually build them before testing them. The assembled files are in a chroot like environment, complete with kernel and everything.

Comment: What do you use to run vm's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this I would build the whole thing in an ISO so once it's working you're done.  To do that you'll need to create an empty ISO to start with

```
truncate -s 100M image.iso
```

Then make sure it has a partition table a partition table (generally it has one automagically)

```
# fdisk -l image.iso
Disk image.iso: 100 MiB, 104857600 bytes, 204800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x602a438a

Device     Boot Start    End Sectors Size Id Type
image.iso1       2048 204799  202752  99M 83 Linux
```

The next thing you want to do is create your filesystem on the .iso but since you want it on the partition and not the raw device you'll need to create an offset loop device to reference the partition.  Note from the previous output that a sector is 512 bytes and the partition starts at sector 2048.  To calculate the offset you'll need in the next step do 512*2048=1048576 bytes.  Then create the offset loop device.

```
losetup --offset 1048576 /dev/loop2 image.iso
```

Now you're ready to create the filesystem and mount it.

```
mkfs.ext4 -O dir_index /dev/loop2
mount /dev/loop2 /mnt/temp
```

The final step is to install grub on the raw iso so that it'll be able to boot.

```
grub-install image.iso
```

Build your system in `/mnt/temp` and when you're ready to test it simply `umount /mnt/temp` and make a vm that boots from your iso.  One note of caution, if you ever boot the iso while it's still mounted you'll almost certainly corrupt your filesystem and have to start over.  Other than that it works pretty slick.